# jQuery animate being shaky

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-animate

I am doing an animation using jQuery to pan an image around slow in a banner-type container. It works almost perfect, but it seems to be a bit jittery. I've tried speeding it up and slowing it down but it still shakes.

I thought at first that it might be a hardware issue and the PC just couldnt handle panning the hi-res image. But I have confirmed that not being the issue by shrinking and reducing the quality of the picture.

You can view the panning image here: http://parkland2.wethink.ca

Animations code:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    letsTravel: function() {
        var horizontalRange = jQuery(this).width() - jQuery(this).parent().width();
        var verticalRange = jQuery(this).height() - jQuery(this).parent().height();
        var halfHeight = div(verticalRange,2);
        //horizontalRange and verticalRange are maximum valid horizontal/vertical offset
        //all coordinates should be below 0 because start point is 0,0
        jQuery(this).animate({left: (horizontalRange-120)*(-1), top: halfHeight*(-1)},20000, 'linear', function(){
            jQuery(this).animate({left: horizontalRange*(-1), top: verticalRange*(-1)},20000, 'linear', function(){
                jQuery(this).animate({left: (horizontalRange/2)*(-1)},10000, 'linear', function(){
                    jQuery(this).animate({left: 0, top: halfHeight*(-1)},20000, 'linear', function(){
                        jQuery(this).animate({top: 0},10000, 'linear');
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }       
});
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is mistake in your code. When the vertical movement is taking place, the horizontal position isn't constant. This causes your problem. Can you provide us with the appropriate function.